# return only values from a categorical variable after filtering values from a calculation in powerbi dax

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, conditional-statements, switch-statement, dax

I have the following table created by a calculated measure:

```
+---------+-------+
|      col| %_calc|
+---------+-------+
| personID|   0.93|
|    empNO|   0.36|
|   gender|   0.65|
|  address|   0.55|
|    ccard|   0.93|
+---------+-------+
```

where
`%_calc = sum according to a condition/sum of all values`. What I would like to do is to return only 'col' values that has %_calc < 0.6. I intend to use the value in a table visual showing only the column values that meets the condition. That means,

```
+---------+-------+
|      col| %_calc|
+---------+-------+
|    empNO|   0.36|
|  address|   0.55|
+---------+-------+
```

but in table visual, or the multi-row card, I only needed to show the words 'empNO' and 'address', without their corresponding values, because their values are less than 0.60 like below:

```
+---------+
|      col|
+---------+
|    empNO|
|  address|
+---------+
```

I tried the following:

```
cols_below60 =
RETURN 
    SWITCH(TRUE(),
        %_calc < 0.6, SELECTEDVALUE(table[fields]))
```

but what I get when I put the measure in a matrix looks like this:

```
+---------+-------+
|      col| %_calc|
+---------+-------+
|    empNO|  empNO|
|  address|address|
+---------+-------+
```

I also tried the following RETURN statement:`RETURN %_calc < 0.6` but returns a boolean table like below :

```
+---------+-------+
|      col| %_calc|
+---------+-------+
| personID|  False|
|    empNO|   True|
|   gender|  False|
|  address|   True|
|    ccard|  False|
+---------+-------+
```

The closest I can make it partially work is the RETURN SWITCH TRUE from above. May I also add, I get the fields I needed to put the fields values and the cols_below60 to get the fields that are less than 60.

###### Update ##### using the second suggested solution, it is not working as expected.

[image]

from above, it is expected to see Expiration only because that is the only field less than 0.6, but I got all the other columns which were not supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECTCOLUMNS( FILTER('Table', 'Table'[%_calc] < 0.6), "col", 'Table'[col])
```

Comment: Please add this to your solution. Your result returns a table. He needs a measure to use it in card visual or table visual. Measure =  CONCATENATEX (SELECTCOLUMNS( FILTER('Table', 'Table'[%_calc] < 0.6), "col", 'Table'[col]),[col],", ")

Comment: I didn't spot that as the question wasn't 100% clear to me. Feel free to add a separate answer to claim the credit if that is what OP requires.

Comment: Hi @David, Your solution is great. I am not that kind of man to go after credits. Also, It is your right to get it; because you solved it.

Comment: Hi, @Ozan, I am using your measure but it is giving me the other columns, those that are higher than 0.6

Comment: @buddingpro oh my god! Strange! Could you please attach the screenshot into your post?

Comment: I also found out that it sometimes repeats the same variable after going through each filter to test

Comment: Hi @buddingpro. That's because context transition is missing. You need to put calculate before the whole expression. Try this code: Measure =
CALCULATE (
    CONCATENATEX (
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[%_calc] < 0.6 ),
            "col", 'Table'[col]
        ),
        [col],
        ", "
    )
)

Comment: Thank you for your diligence, it still does not work, in the individual calculation, I only have one field less than 0.6, but your formula is showing 13 columns. And the values keep changing when I test when I filter ID in the slicer. However, I was able to make it work using the filter within the desktop app.

Comment: Sure? I tested it ,and It is working . You need to check it again . I am grouping by [col] column , and only showing values less than 0.60.